# How to skip the properties from pom.xml

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, pom.xml

I want to set properties value true in pom.xml and false into the script-
pom.xml-

```
  <properties>
            <swagger.codegen.plugin.version>3.0.0-rc0</swagger.codegen.plugin.version>`enter code here`
            <swagger.codegen.plugin.version>3.0.3</swagger.codegen.plugin.version>
            <swagger.codegen.generators.version>1.0.3</swagger.codegen.generators.version>
            <swagger.lang>jaxrs-jersey</swagger.lang>
        </properties>
```

check.sh-

```
mvn validate -Dmaven.exec.skip -DskipTests -P copyright,license
```

I have added skip tag but its not working for this plugins

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>io.swagger.codegen.v3</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-codegen-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${swagger.codegen.plugin.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>generate-folder-pojo</id>
                    <phase>validate</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generate</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <skip>true</skip>
                        <inputSpec>${swagger.inputSpec}/folder_definition.json</inputSpec>
                        <language>${swagger.lang}</language>
                        <templateDirectory>${swagger.api}/template</templateDirectory>
                        <verbose>false</verbose>
                  
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                </executions>
                </plugin>
```

Comment: Refer: https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
 <skip>true</skip>
```

Try

```
<skip>${maven.exec.skip}</skip>
```